# Lifting an equivalence relation on elements to a relation on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

If every element of $A$ is equivalent (by an equivalence relation $R$) to some element of $B$

> $\forall x\in A\ldotp \exists y \in B\ldotp x\,R\,y$

and vice versa

> $\forall y\in B\ldotp \exists x \in A\ldotp x\,R\,y$

then what can I deduce about the relationship between $A$ and $B$? I certainly can't say that they're *equal*, but they would seem to be equivalent in some sense. Perhaps one could say something to do with bijections here? Or perhaps equivalence classes?

---

<sup>My motivation for asking is that I have a theorem of the form outlined above, and I would like to find a simpler way to state it. Originally my $R$ was just straightforward equality ($=$), and then I could just deduce $A = B$. Now my $R$ is no longer $=$, but I'd still like to keep the statement of my theorem nice and succinct if I can.</sup>

Comment: Isn't an equivalence relation only defined between members of the same set ?

Comment: @TomCollinge yeah they are, say some set $U$. Then in this setting, we (most likely) have $A,B \subseteq U$ :)




Also, John, thanks for the context (ie the text in small font). Found it helpful!

Answer (score 3):

From your question it seems that the relation $R$ is defined in $A\cup B$.

You can therefore say that from your assumptions, as sets, we have $A/R=B/R=(A\cup B)/R$

Indeed, any equivalence class in $(A\cup B)/R$ contains both an element of $A$ and an element of $B$.

So the natural inclusions

$A/R\hookrightarrow (A\cup B)/R$ and $B/R\hookrightarrow (A\cup B)/R$ are onto.

Comment: Excellent, I had been hoping I would be able to say something short and sweet like $A/R = B/R$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This' neat :)

From the observation,

$
\;\;\; A \subseteq B
\\\equiv \forall a \in A. a \in B
\\\equiv \forall a \in A. \exists b \in B. b = a
$

We can generalize this preorder from any equivalence relation $\sim$ by defining
$$A \subseteq_\sim B :\equiv (\forall a \in A. \exists b \in B. a \sim b)$$

(Now this is indeed a preorder ---ie reflexive and transitive ... I couldn't prove antisymmetry.)

Anyhow, from this we can extend $\sim$ to sets by
$$A \approx B :\equiv A \subseteq_\sim B \land B \subseteq_\sim A$$

Now this is indeed an equivalence relation and it is induced by the given $\sim$. We may call this *set equivalence by $\sim$-extensionality*, for example.

I had fun doing this; hope it helps!

---

Edit: it'd be nice to relate $\approx$ with $\sim$; we can show
$$A \approx B \implies A/\sim \,= B/\sim$$
Indeed,
$\;\;\;X \subseteq_\sim Y
\\\equiv \forall x \in X. \exists y \in Y. x \sim y
\\\equiv \forall x \in X. \exists y \in Y. x/\sim \,=\, y /\sim
\\\equiv \forall x \in X. \exists y \in Y. x/\sim \,=\, y /\sim \,\in Y/\sim
\\\Rightarrow \forall x \in X. x/\sim \,\in Y/\sim
\\\equiv X/\sim \;\subseteq\, Y/\sim
$
and thus
$\;\;\; A \approx B
\\\equiv A \subseteq_\sim B \subseteq_\sim A
\\\Rightarrow A/\sim \subseteq B/\sim \subseteq A/\sim
\\\equiv A/\sim \,=\, B/\sim 
$

It'd be nice if the converse also held; we'll leave that as an exercise to the diligent reader/poster ;)

Comment: Thanks for this Moses `:-)`. I wonder: to what extent is your *set equivalence by $\approx$-extensionality* ($A \approx B$) the same as the $A/{\approx} = B/{\approx}$ suggestion by user126154?

Comment: Some progress has been recorded; see edited solution :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks Moses! I'll have a read in a mo, but just a quick remark: you get better formatting of your quotients if you type `A/{\approx}` (gives $A/{\approx}$) instead of `A/\approx` (gives $A/\approx$).

Comment: Thanks! That was really bothering me and I didn't know what to do. I don't know much about the TeX system of stackexchange, but I was really impressed by the juxtaposition of my calculations above ( in the edit): it just happened, I didn't do anything :)

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is an equivalence relation on $X$ and $A,B\subseteq X$, then your statement is equivalent to: The partition of $X$ into equivalence classes is such that each equivalence class intersecting $A\cup B$ intersects *both* $A$ *and* $B$. I do not think much more can be said.